# Cannot read property '1' of null. Variable set up

Tags: javascript, jquery

If there is no match it assigns null to the variable, if there is a match it assigns the second match to the variable.

That's how I thought it would be, but when it returns null, it still checks the rest of the code for when it would be false. So then I get a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null`.

How could I work around this part to make it work and not give me an error?

```
var matches = $("#search input").val().match(pattern);    
var id = [];
id["new"] = (typeof matches === null) ? null : matches[1]; // <--
```

Comment: check if matches has a value first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`typeof` operator always returns a string which will never === null.

Since the result of `$("#search input").val().match(pattern)` will always be `null` when nothing matched and an array when matched, `null` is falsy value, so you could just do:

```
id["new"] = matches ? matches[1] ：null;
```

Or even:

```
id["new"] = matches && matches[1];
```

Comment: Thank you. What is happening with that second piece of code? It works, but I'm curious what is happening right there, because I don't understand it.

Comment: @KidDiamond `A && B` returns `B` if `A` is truthy value, otherwise returns `A`. since `matches` is null when not matched, and you want null in this case, so the code could be simply to this.

Comment: IS your first one not the wrong way round? If `matches` is truthy you get `null` out...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
id["new"] = (matches == null) ? null : matches[1];
```

`.match()` returns `null` if no match found.